# sustituir letras de un string por *

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio hace días....y estoy desesperado ya.

Se trata de un ahorcado típico, hasta ahí todo bien, pero el tema es que la plabra que hay que adivinar se selecciona ALEATORIAMENTE de una lista en un .txt dentro del proyecto. Esto también está ok.

Una vez seleccionada la palabra, se tiene que mostrar la misma palabra sustituyendo sus letras por * y entonces comienza el juego, con lo típico: preguntar al usuario para que introduzca letras por consola y bla bla bla... eso también está oK.

Mi problema viene al inicio, justo después de algoritmo de selección aleatoria, porque como no puedo preveer qué palabra será, no puedo saber qué letras tengo que sustituir por *, ni tampoco cual es la longitud de la palabra, asi que tampoco lo puedo hacer por charAt()...

Si pudierais ayudarme os lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Tu pregunta resulta interesante, sin embargo está mal formulada. Es imposible que te ayudemos sin que pongas cómo es tu código. Así de primeras te diría que uses un bufferedreader para almacenar la palabra en una variables del tipo `String` (con la S mayúscula) y le hagas al String un `.length()` para saber el número de caracteres y crear otra variable con tantos asteriscos como caracteres hayas obtenido.

Comment: `"palabra".replace("*", "\\*")` cambiará todos los caracteres de tu string por asteriscos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es recoger la palabra del txt, copiarla a otro string auxiliar, y este convertirlo todo a * mediante charAt() y auxiliar.lenght, asi tendrás la palabra "descifrada" con la que comparar cuando el usuario use el programa, y la auxiliar donde ir desbloqueando esos * por letras cuando acierte.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]